Looking for the title of an old sci-fi book where a human newspaper columnist is secretly married to an alien woman
In the book, the human man and his wife help her people to search the Earth for tiny, rice sized particles that have immense power. They need to find the particles first, in order to   to keep a different alien species from getting to them first and using them as a weapon.
I read the book in the mid to late 70s. It was probably written in the late 60s or early 70s.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any recollection of the cover of the book?  Was it a paperback or hardcover?
